# setItemChecked() function to persist selection

Tags: java, android

I would like to persist list item selection like it is on first picture(Circle Fragment Example), so when list item is selected it should stay marked as "selected". What I have is two different project I found on net. On first picture is behavior I want to achieve.
On second image(Fragment Basics) you can see that  list item that has been selected do not persist "selected" state. What I don't understand is next:

In both case function that is being called is setItemChecked(position,true) but seems like different behavior is applied.

[image: Behavior I want to achieve]

[image: Once the list item is being marked as "clicked", selection goes away]

Comment: Actually, I do think that the background of the items in the second picture does not have a "Checked" background

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by that? I don't understand. Although I searched google with "checked background android" I cannot understand you. Can you give some refs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if on your second project the choice mode of your list view is set to choice_mode_single

And if the resource parameter of the ArrayAdapter is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1

Comment: Yeap!,that was it! Thanks a lot! I really spent much time figuring what causes this. It was because of "simple_list_item_1" instead of "simple_list_item_activated_1"

Comment: Glad it has helped you.